# Angular's ActivatedRoute to use same component for 'new' and 'edit'

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-activatedroute

I don't fully understand how to use the ActivatedRoute service. In my application the code to create or edit a user is exactly the same with the only difference being that an "edit" first queries for the current values from a webservice whereas the "create" does not.

What I'd like to have is a route like so:

```js
{path: 'client/:id', component: ClientEditComponent}
```

and then if the `:id` is provided I'm doing an edit, and if not I'm doing a create. There's so many different ways that I've seen of reading from the `ActivatedRoute` service that I don't know what's right at this point.

Am I just looking at snapshot, do I subscribe to something, etc...

Comment: Are you saying that if an `:id` is not provided you still want it to use the `ClientEditComponent`?

Comment: Yes, that would be the goal.

Comment: Is there an issue with making another path that just looks for `client/` and points to the `ClientEditComponent`?

Comment: Nope, that wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Great, for future reference: People who downvote but don't comment could be doing it for a myriad of reasons, but the two common ones are that a question is (Lacking Research | Unclear | Not Useful) or they just break good practices. In your case, being able to copy and paste the line of code you posted and deleting `:id` makes this not that useful to the community. I'm not trying to demean or offend, just giving you my perspective of the downvotes.

Comment: But the true question here is understanding what the right way to pull that ID is.

Answer (score 0):

`paramMap` provides you with a way of pulling the parameters (like `:id`) from the url. It also provides a `has(name: string)` function which allows for easy testing to check if a parameter even exists and event a `get(name: string)` function for getting the value of a parameter. Check out the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/ParamMap) for more details.